# Logic Clarification for sorting an array of array in python based off the value of a number using merge sort?

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, mergesort

I want to sort an array of array with merge sort based off the last number in each internal array from highest value to lowest value:

```
arraySample=[['a', 'new', 3], ['a', 'new', 3],  ['b', 'new', 1], ['c', 'old', 2], ['c', 'old', 2], ['d', 'new', 1],['a', 'new', 3],['e', 'old', 3],['e', 'old', 3],['e', 'old', 3]]
```

In addition , I want to make sure that it is also sorted in a way such that the elements with the same name should still be ordered together .

I.e the 3 elements of 'a' should be ordered together , followed by the 3 elements of 'e' etc..

For now here is the code I have and at the bottom is the output:

## Merge

```
def merge(arr1, arr2, index):
    arr3 = []
    sizeA = len(arr1)
    sizeB = len(arr2)

    indexa = indexb = 0

    while indexa < sizeA and indexb < sizeB:
        if arr1[indexa][index] >= arr2[indexb][index]:
            arr3.append(arr1[indexa])
            indexa += 1
        else:
            arr3.append(arr2[indexb])
            indexb += 1

    arr3.extend(arr1[indexa:sizeA])
    arr3.extend(arr2[indexb:sizeB])
    return arr3
```

## Merge Sort

```
def mergesort(array, index=-1):
    size = len(array)

    if size == 1:
        return array

    midindex = size // 2
    firsthalf = array[0:midindex]
    secondhalf = array[midindex:size]

    firsthalf = mergesort(firsthalf, index)
    secondhalf = mergesort(secondhalf, index)
    array = merge(firsthalf, secondhalf, index)

    return array
mergesort(arraySample)
for i in arraySample:
    print(str(i)+"\n")
```

## Output

```
['a', 'new', 3]

['a', 'new', 3]

['b', 'new', 1]

['c', 'old', 2]

['c', 'old', 2]

['d', 'new', 1]

['a', 'new', 3]

['e', 'old', 3]

['e', 'old', 3]

['e', 'old', 3]
```

However the expected output is:

```
['a', 'new', 3]

['a', 'new', 3]

['a', 'old', 3]

['e', 'old', 3]

['e', 'new', 3]

['e', 'old', 3] 

['c', 'old', 2]

['c', 'old', 2]

['b', 'new', 1]

['d', 'new', 1]
```

May I know how could improve or change the code to solve this issue? I am a beginner to Data Structures and Algorithms but I am trying to learn. Please note that I am trying to avoid the usage of external methods and libraries as well as in-built methods. Thank you !

Comment: First of all, `mergesort` doesn't modify the list inplace, therefore replace `mergesort(arrayB)` near the end by `arrayB = mergesort(arrayB)` (shouldn't this be `arraySample` instead?).

Comment: Hi thank you for pointing it out , I have edited it as shown (copied a previous version of the code by accident) . However, the issue still stands

Comment: *"elements with the same name should still be ordered together"*: also if their last member is different? Or do you mean to sort by the last member and (when there are ties) then by the first member?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code currently uses `index` to determine how items should be ordered, and you use -1 (the default) for it. But as you want to add the first member (name) into the order logic, you need to pass along more information. It could be a second index (which would be 0), but maybe it is better to pass a key *function* as argument. Then let that function return a value (a tuple) that determines the order of the given element.

Note that the sorted list is *returned* by your `mergesort` function, so the main code should capture that returned list.

Here is your code updated with that idea:

```
def merge(arr1, arr2, key):  # takes a key argument
    arr3 = []
    sizeA = len(arr1)
    sizeB = len(arr2)

    indexa = indexb = 0

    while indexa < sizeA and indexb < sizeB:
        if key(arr1[indexa]) < key(arr2[indexb]):  # call key to determine order
            arr3.append(arr1[indexa])
            indexa += 1
        else:
            arr3.append(arr2[indexb])
            indexb += 1

    arr3.extend(arr1[indexa:])
    arr3.extend(arr2[indexb:])
    return arr3

def mergesort(array, key):
    size = len(array)

    if size == 1:
        return array

    midindex = size // 2
    firsthalf = array[0:midindex]
    secondhalf = array[midindex:size]

    firsthalf = mergesort(firsthalf, key)
    secondhalf = mergesort(secondhalf, key)
    array = merge(firsthalf, secondhalf, key)

    return array

arraySample=[['a', 'new', 3], ['e', 'old', 3],['a', 'new', 3],  ['b', 'new', 1], ['c', 'old', 2], ['c', 'old', 2], ['d', 'new', 1],['a', 'new', 3],['e', 'old', 3],['e', 'old', 3]]

# Pass a key function:
#    descending by member 2: `-a[2]`
#    ascending by member 0: `a[0]`

result = mergesort(arraySample, lambda a: (-a[2], a[0]))

for elem in result:
    print(elem)
```